# Can't enable CheckBounce plugin for Sublime Text 2

Tags: plugins, sublimetext2

I try to configure Sublime Text 2 on windows 7

I installed <kbd>CheckBounce</kbd> plugin from: followed [link](https://github.com/phyllisstein/CheckBounce)

but I get "Enable Spellcheck" disabled.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

[image]

**[Edit]**

I have default configuration = user configuration

PackageControll.sublimesettings - user:

```
{
"installed_packages":
[
    "JsFormat",
    "Package Control",
    "SublimeLinter",
    "SyntaxChecker"
]
}
```

Comment: It might not support Windows. I only see OS X mentioned [CheckBounce on GitHub](https://github.com/phyllisstein/CheckBounce).

Comment: thanks mate, didnt notice it